# Binary Translation

Tags: c, file, binary, io, hex

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned char data[1];

  FILE *f = fopen("bill.jpg", "rb");

  while (!feof(f)) {
    if (fread(data, 1, 1, f) > 0) {
      printf("0x%02x\n", data[0]);
    }
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Is this the right? I am worried because if I view the file using hexdump, I get completely different output.

Comment: *completely* was a bit OTT, It's backwards (as pointed out below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should correctly print the first byte of the file in hex.

Check the documentation for the Hexdump utility used, or tell us which platform is being used.  Some dump utilities display the bytes in reverse order on each line to make little-endian reading somewhat more intuitive—once you understand what it is doing.

Comment: Yes, I did notice it was backwards; do you know why it does that? I can imagine this would be enormously confusing.

Comment: On little-endian machines such as 80x86, VAX, etc., it makes interpreting a series of bytes which form a larger quantity more intuitive to read.  For example, the value 1000 is 0x3e8.  The value in a 32-bit register looks like `00 00 03 e8`, but when stored in memory as a 32-bit value, the least significant byte is at the lowest address, so looking the bytes in standard increasing order shows `e8 03 00 00`.  A dumper which reverses the line shows something more natural—for multibyte values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but no -- `while (!feof(f))` is essentially always wrong -- it'll typically appear to read the last item in the file twice. Here's a reasonably usable hex dumper I wrote a few years ago:

```
/* public domain by Jerry Coffin, tested with MS C 10.0 and BC 4.5
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long offset = 0;
    FILE *input;
    int bytes, i, j;
    unsigned char buffer[16];
    char outbuffer[60];

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: dump filename [filename...]");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (j=1;j<argc; ++j) {

        if ( NULL ==(input=fopen(argv[j], "rb")))
            continue;

        printf("\n%s:\n", argv[j]);

        while (0 < (bytes=fread(buffer, 1, 16, input))) {
            sprintf(outbuffer, "%8.8lx: ", offset+=16);
            for (i=0;i<bytes;i++) {
                sprintf(outbuffer+10+3*i, "%2.2X ",buffer[i]);
                if (!isprint(buffer[i]))
                    buffer[i] = '.';
            }
            printf("%-60s %*.*s\n", outbuffer, bytes, bytes, buffer);
        }
        fclose(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But here, `feof` is essentially redundant rather than suffering the print-last-twice bug, though, as the original code does check the return value of `fread`.

Comment: @Charles -- right, in this case the bug is hidden (or at least its effects are).